# Can't get data from table with php and sqlite db

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to echo onto my screen all the data is my 'userdata' table. i have looked around and found this code but when i run it i get a HTTP ERROR 500.
this is my code that im trying to use:

```
<?php
    $database = new SQLite3('home.db');

    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM userdata");
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: You can't echo the result. I'd suggest reading [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php), which gives plenty of examples to show what you need to do.

Comment: If you're just trying to see the result set for debug/visualization purposes, wrap the result, like this: print_r($result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `$database->query()` method will return an `SQLite3Result` object which you can't just "echo". Instead, you should loop through all the results like so:

```
<?php
    $database = new SQLite3('home.db');

    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM userdata");

    while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

The `$row` variable inside the `while` loop will be an array. Use the appropriate index to get the value of a single column if necessary.